# Authenticating user over AJAX on symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Im calling this script over ajax:

```
$userRepository = $this->getDoctrine( )->getRepository( 'DonePunctisBundle:User' );
$user           = $userRepository->findOneByUsername( array( 'username' => $fbuser['email'] ) );

$this->_authenticateUser($user);


protected function _authenticateUser( User $user )  {
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles() );
    $this->get( 'security.context' )->setToken( $token );
}
```

No errors, but the user do not gets login. What i need to do?

Comment: Are you using Symfony 2.1? If so, try adding this:                 `$session = $this->get('session'); $session->set('_security_' . $firewallName, serialize($token)); $session->save();`
In general, authenticating like this is not a great idea. It's better to use a login form

Comment: The name of your firewall? Whatever you specified in security.yml

Comment: @Squazic ok, by adding you mean to add your code to my function or to create a new one? Can you elaborate your comment as an asnwer please

Comment: I meant to add it after your code

Answer (score 0):

Just pass user password in UsernamePasswordToken.

```
new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
```